# Prove that the coefficients of F(x) are positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series, formal-power-series, algebraic-combinatorics

Consider the formal power series
$$F(x) = \sum_{k\ge0}(x+x^2-x^3)^k$$
How can I show that the coefficients of F(x) are positive integers?

I wrote the F as
$F(x) = 1/(1-x-x^2 +x^3) = 1/((x-1)^2(x+1))$

But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: $F(x)=1/(1-x-x^2+x^3)$ lets you get a simple recurrence for the coefficients. You can easily use induction to prove from there. Or use the original formula to show that the coefficient of $x^n$ is unaffected by terms $k>n,$ so each coefficient is a sum of a finite set of integers. You can use your factoring of $1-x-x^2+x^3$ to get a partial fraction decomposition to get a closed formula for the coefficients. The coefficient of $x^n$ will be of the form $an+b+c(-1)^n,$ for fixed constants $a,b,c.$

Comment: All of what @ThomasAndrews writes is true, but it's far simpler than that: $F(x)$ is the sum of polynomials with integer coefficients, so it itself is a power series with integer coefficients. (assuming you already believe it converges)

Comment: Hint: write $F(x)$ as $$\frac1{1-x}\times \frac1{1-x^2}$$This makes it clear the coefficients of $F$ are positive.

Comment: @GregMartin The goal is to show the coefficients are _positive_ integers.

Comment: So I need to turn those two into geometric series? $\sum_{n\ge0}(x)^n \sum_{n\ge0}(x^2)^n$?

Comment: This is just OEIS sequence A008619 https://oeis.org/A008619  where $a(n) = 1 + \lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, t^n = \frac{1}{1-t-t^2+t^3}$$
the difference equation $$ a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} - a_{n-3}$$ is obtained with the initial conditions $a_{0} = a_{1} = 1, a_{2} = 2$. Making use of this leads to one way of showing all the coefficients are positive.

By factoring the generating function and then using it in the form
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-t-t^2+t^3} &= \frac{1}{(1+t)(1-t)^2} = \frac{1}{4} \, \left( \frac{1}{1+t} + \frac{1}{1-t} + \frac{2}{(1-t)^2} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( (-1)^n + 1 + 2 \, (n+1)\right)t^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2 n + 3 + (-1)^n}4\,t^n
\end{align}
then it can be seen that $$a_{n} = \frac{2 n + 3 + (-1)^n}{4} $$ which shows all the coefficients are positive.

Another way is to show that $$ a_{n} =\left\lfloor{ \frac{n+2}{2}}\right\rfloor. $$

Comment: Can you explain how you got $(2n + 3+ (-1)^n)/2? I get something different and I can't find my mistake

Comment: @AndromedaPapa   an update to the solution has been added.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had forgotten about the 2!

Answer (score 0):

Following great hint of @Mike Earnest  for $a\ge b \ge 0 $ we have the expression with a positive expansion

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^a (1+x)^b} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{a-b}\cdot (1- x^2)^b}$$